# Java Add span to image background color

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics

i want to add additional space in images, lets call it "span".

My code is:

```
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight()+200, image2.getType());

        Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight()+100);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 100, null);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.dispose();
        RenderedImage rendImage = newImage;

        String newUrl8006002 = splitUrl[0]+"-800x6002.jpg";
        File file = new File(newUrl8006002);
        ImageIO.write(rendImage, "jpg", file);
```

The problem is, that image at the bottom has black background and i expect white (at the top is white).

Do you know what to change to add white background in whole image?

Comment: change `image.getHeight()+100` to `image.getHeight()+200`

Comment: Or better yet, use `newImage.getWidth()` and `newImage.getHeight()` so you're actually using the values of the image itself, rather then some set of magic numbers

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
static BufferedImage growY(BufferedImage im, int span, Color color)
{
  BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(im.getWidth(), im.getHeight()+span, im.getType());
  int topSpan = span/2;
  int botSpan = span - topSpan;
  Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();
  g.setColor(color);
  g.fillRect(0, 0, newImage.getWidth(), topSpan);
  g.fillRect(0, topSpan+im.getHeight(), newImage.getWidth(), botSpan);
  g.drawImage(im, 0, topSpan, null);
  g.dispose();    
  return newImage;
}
```